# How to import a file from another folder in lua?

Tags: lua

I am importing a file from a different folder.

Here's what I mean:

```
      import *c://players.lua* to *c://terrain/main.lua*
```

players.lua:

```
local user1 = "user1"
```

main.lua:

```
require "terrain/players.lua"
local spawn = 10
if user1 = false then
   user1 = true, spawn
end
```

I haven't getting errors because I only have a lua editor.
if I get errors then I have to change it to `require 'file:///c://Desktop/g/players.lua'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xpcall` to check if the require function thrown an error

In `folder1/init.lua` and `folder2/init.lua`

```lua
return {
  printHelloWorld = function()
    print('Hello World!')
  end
}
```

In `main.lua`

```lua
-- First value that xpcall return is the status code `status: Boolean`
-- Second value is the error message `error: String`
-- Third value is the return of the function `retVal: Any`
local ok, err, lib = xpcall(function()
  return require 'folder1/init.lua'
end, function()
  return require 'folder2/init.lua'
end)

lib.printHelloWorld()
```

References:

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_error_handling.htm